# xpath union operator with VTD XML Parser

Tags: vtd-xml

Can someone please post an example for using union operator (|) with VTD XML parser ?
Below is not working in VTD XML parser but works in jxpath parser.
/a | /b

Comment: Not working? I doubt it but will check

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. If there is a correct format to use union operator, please paste that as well.

Comment: what part of it is not working? xpath compilation fail? or evaluation fail?

Comment: evaluation is failing. For example, the value returned is null if a has no value but b has value. The expectation is to return b's value with union operator.

Comment: The xpath which I am trying is   /a | /b.  Is there any specific format to use union operator with VTD XML parser ?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: can you post your code first?

Comment: I am using 2.13 version. I am just using a simple example from VTD XML home page - xml having 2 elements - a and b and using the code sample to  evaluate the xpath (/a | /b). Also, if you have any working example with union operator, please post it here.

Comment: it works for me... no problem detected what so ever... 2.13_1 is the latest version... so get that first... if that still does not work... I want to see your code

Comment: Thanks. I will get the latest version. Can you please post the working example ? I can use that for reference.

Comment: Can you please post the working example with union operator here ? It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a quick example of union expression in action.

```
import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.NavException;
import com.ximpleware.VTDException;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;


/**
 * An issue that seems to exist in VTD-XML 2.12 and 2.13 (but not 2.11) that causes lookups for default namespace nodes
 * to also pickup non-default namespaced nodes.
 */
public class VtdAutoPilotXpathIssueTest {

  private static final String XML = "<a xmlns:x=\"" + "urn:test" + "\"><b id=\"1\"/><x:b id=\"2\"/><b id=\"3\"/></a>";
  public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException{
      VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
      vg.setDoc(XML.getBytes());
      vg.parse(false);
      VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
      AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
      ap.declareXPathNameSpace("abc", "urn:test");
      ap.selectXPath("//b|/a");
      int i=0;
      while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
          System.out.println(" token "+ vn.toRawString(i));
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you please try the other way ? (/a|/b)  or (//a|/b).   This was not working for me last week. Usually, this works when the variable defined in the left side of xpath has a value but it doesn't work when the variable defined in the right side only has a value.

Comment: of course you can but //b won't return a single node for the xml file above.

Comment: Please try this XML along with the below changes. Rest of the code remains the same. The expectation is to get b's value (1) though c has no value. The union operator can get any of the values  which is not null. But I am getting a null value.

Comment: private static final String XML = "<a xmlns:x=\"" + "urn:test" + "\"><b>1</b><c></c></a>";                                                ap.selectXPath("//c|/b");     and in the while loop, you can add the below:    vn.recoverNode(i);                                                                       System.out.println(" value " + vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));

Comment: Can you please try this and confirm ? It will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, can you please try the above and confirm ?